# How to change my widget icon after it is installed, android

Tags: android, text, icons, widget

My code right now for my main.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="146dip"
android:layout_height="72dip"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/widgetlayout">
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button_two" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"></Button>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center" android:textColor="@color/text_color" android:id="@+id/NameOfApp"></TextView>
```

As you can see it is very basic, just a button and a textview.
However, after I click on the button and enter a name for my app, I want the textview to change to the name I gave it. I save the name in SharedPreferences after the user clicks the save settings button inside the widget.

Answer (score 0):

handle the on click of button and get the text from textview and use textview.setText to change the text .Though the question "on how to change the widget icon " and the explanation looked different .

Comment: Well I know how to use .setText but the user enters the configuration settings in configure.xml and the main.xml controls the textview for the widget. even when I change the main.xml however it doesnt work